# select checkbox tag python

Tags: python, json, xml

If have a XML document like this :

```
<!-- Location -->
<w:t>Lokacioni:</w:t>
<w:t>Kucni:</w:t>
<w:t>Extension:</w:t>
<w:t>Hajvali –Prishtinë</w:t>
<w:t>Rr. “ Dëshmorët e Gollakut “</w:t>
<w:t>P. N. Prishtinë</w:t>

<!-- Date -->
<w:t>Dat:</w:t>
<w:t>Datum:</w:t>
<w:t>Date:</w:t>
<w:t xml:space="preserve"> </w:t>

<!-- Free text - contains time and description-->
<w:t>1.</w:t><w:t>08:05 Aksident trafiku me dëme materiale Audi dhe Kombi te Kisha Graqanic</w:t>

<!-- Checkboxes - 1 means it is checked -->
<w:t>Informuar:PK</w:t><w:checkBox><w:sizeAuto/><w:default w:val="1"/></w:checkBox> 
<w:t>SHME</w:t><w:checkBox><w:sizeAuto/><w:default w:val="0"/></w:checkBox>
<w:t>SHZSH</w:t><w:checkBox><w:sizeAuto/><w:default w:val="0"/></w:checkBox>
<w:t>,Shërbimet tjera</w:t><w:checkBox><w:sizeAuto/><w:default w:val="0"/></w:checkBox>
```

In python I want to select values from that xml that is generated from a .docx document, that contain checkbox. I wrote code like this:

```
WordNameSpace = '{http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main}'
para_tag = WordNameSpace + 'p'
text_tag = WordNameSpace + 't'
checkBox_tag = WordNameSpace + 'checkBox'
def get_docx_text(path):
    document = zipfile.ZipFile(path)
    xml_content = document.read('word/document.xml')
    document.close()
    tree = XML(xml_content)

    paragraphs = []
    for paragraph in tree.getiterator(checkBox_tag):
        texts = [node.text for node in paragraph.getiterator(text_tag) if node.text]
        if texts:
            paragraphs.append(''.join(texts))

    return paragraphs

results = get_docx_text('test.docx')

print results
```

when i print results variable, result is only `[]` ? Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating through every checkbox tag (`<w:checkBox>`) on this line:

```
for paragraph in tree.getiterator(checkBox_tag):
```

Then inside that you are searching for text tags (`<w:t>`) inside those:

```
    texts = [node.text for node in paragraph.getiterator(text_tag) if node.text]
```

However, if you look at your XML document, none of your checkboxes have any text inside them, for example:

```
<w:checkBox><w:sizeAuto/><w:default w:val="0"/></w:checkBox>
```

So `paragraphs` never has anything added, so `get_docx_text` always returns `[]`.

Double check what you actually want to iterate through, and if you actually want the *siblings* of checkboxes, and not children.